# Refreshing combo box in Python add-in of ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy, python-addin

I've got an add-in with a combo box and want to refresh the list in the combo box after an event in one of the other tools in the same add-in toolbar.

Can I call the combo box somehow to refresh it outside of the object's onSelChange event?

Comment: Can I see your code solution please, I have the same problem. I need to link a couple of combos. thank you and best regards!

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE!  One thing though - this would make a good Comment on the previous Answer but is itself not an Answer to the Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to sort this one out.  I managed to do that by adding a method in the combo box class, initiated them in the button class (where I wanted to refresh the combo box from) and then called the methods from within the button class.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

cboSetup1 = None
cboSetup2 = None

class btn1(object):
    """Implementation for Class_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        combo1 = cbobox1()
        combo1.btnPopulate()
        combo2 = cbobox2()
        combo2.btnPopulate()

class cbobox1(object): 
    """Implementation for Class_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        self.items = cboSetup1
    def btnPopulate(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        self.items = []
    for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        self.items.append(layer.name)
    global cboSetup1
        cboSetup1 = self.items

class cbobox2(object):
    """Implementation for Class_addin.combobox_1 (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        self.items = cboSetup2
    def btnPopulate(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        self.items = []
    for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        self.items.append(layer.name)
    global cboSetup2
        cboSetup2 = self.items
```