# Forcing ArcMap Add-in ComboBox to refresh using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, add-in

I am having problems with an add-in combobox that doesn't refresh.  When the currently selected item is removed from items collection, the name remains visible in the text area.

It should show the combobox's caption, but that doesn't happen until the mouse is moved over it.

Is there a way to force it to refresh programmatically ?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52383/refresh-combo-box-in-add-in

Comment: @Geog That's for a Python AddIn (ArcPy) whereas this is for an ArcMap AddIn (ArcObjects)